# Remove style attribut HTML with Twig

Tags: html, symfony, twig

Hi I'm using **striptags** to remove **img** markup in a variable which content html.

```
{{ trick.content|
striptags('<br><p><h1><h2><h3><a><strong><i><b><u><li><div><span><button>')|raw }}
```

But I would also like to remove every style attribut in every markup.

I don't find a twig filter to do that. Does that exist?

Comment: Nope but you could write your [own](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a twig extension:

```
namespace FM\AppBundle\Twig\Extension;

class AmpExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('amp', array($this, 'ampFilter')),
        );
    }

    public function ampFilter($string)
    {
        $allowedMarkup = '<br><p><h1><h2><h3><h4><a><strong><ul><i><b><u><li><div><button>';
        $string = \strip_tags($string, $allowedMarkup);

        $string = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i', '$1', $string);

        return $string;
    }
}
```